# In Zend Framework 2, how to see the profiler

Tags: symfony, zend-framework2

Can anybody please tell me how to see the profiler like menu in zendframework 2. In Symfony2 or in symfony 1, we have profiler like

[image: Symfony 1 profiler]

[image: Symfony 2 profiler]

The profilers in symfony, are visible when added as *_dev, for app modules, Likewise, how to see the profiler in ZF2

Answer (score 6):

It's called [`ZendDeveloperTools`](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendDeveloperTools) and there's another one called [`BjyProfiler`](https://github.com/bjyoungblood/BjyProfiler) (which requires ZDT) that may be of interest, too.

Ultimately Modules are responsible to add their own profilers into the toolbar.

## Installation

The easiest way to install these modules is through the use of [composer](https://getcomposer.org/). Open up the CLI at your project root and then run the following command:

```
php composer.phar require zendframework/zend-developer-tools:dev-master
```

Doing this will update your `/vendor` folder to include the ZendDeveloperTools. All that's left for you to do is to actually load ZDT, too. I suggest registering ZDT as a first module within your `/config/application.config.php`

```
return array(
    'ZendDeveloperTools',
    'Application',
    // And as many more as you have/need
);
```

In case you're still doomed with running an old PHP Version (less than 5.4) you'll further need to add the following line at the very start of your `/public/index.php`

```
<?php 
define('REQUEST_MICROTIME', microtime(true));

//everything else that was previously there
```

Now you're good to go.

Comment: If you use Doctrine2, then there is zend module for doctrine, which will add logger and mapping info to the toolbar too.

Comment: @user1786423 that's what i mentioned about Modules being responsible for that. DoctrineModule - in this case - does that. But ZDT is always required.

Comment: @Sam, Hey, it looks like symfony2 prefiler :), Have one doubt, how to hide the profiler, when the project is pushed to live/production.

Comment: http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/tutorials/config.advanced.html#environment-specific-system-configuration